# Can I modify an existing certificate to run on multiple hostnames?

Tags: https, security-certificate

I've been investigating and I found instructions on how to [create an SSL certificate with multiple hostnames](http://lanestechblog.blogspot.com/2009/04/creating-ssl-certificates-with-multiple.html), but I need to know whether I can modify an existing certificate (not create a new certificate) to allow multiple hostnames.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't.

If the certificate is self-signed (i.e. you generated it), then you can try to re-create it with existing key pair and other attributes, but even then if some application has saved hashes of the old certificate, it will complain that you have changed certificates.

If the certificate is not yours, then forget it.

Comment: +1: The signing of the certificate locks it in place (via a cryptographic hash) and _any_ changes would need to be re-signed.

Comment: then, can i create a new certificate, specifying the thumbprint that i wanted?

Comment: @EstebanLopez no, you can't. The purpose of the hash and of certificate signature is to ensure integrity of the certificate. And you want to hack the certificate. That won't work.